# Extracting Google Ads CIDs using Google Sheets Regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-lookarounds, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create a regex that will extract CIDs from a cell that contains both text and CIDs.Here is an example feild of text I would like to extract the CIDs from:

Example1:

```
Pokemon FY19 - Instream
261-963-9423
Pokemon - pokedex FY19 - Bumper
334-724-7943
```

Example2:

```
Instream: 856-613-9156
Bumper: 999-448-5246
```

The CIDs are the `XXX-XXX-XXXX` ids.

I have tried this `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}")` but it only returns the first CID in the field when I need it to return all.

I expect the out but to be `261-963-9423 334-724-7943`, but the output is just `261-963-9423`

Comment: thats in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove all lines except the lines that start with digits

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?:^|\n)[A-Za-z_-].*",)
```

Or change all matching ids to `(.*)` and extract them later:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\Q"&REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}","\\E(.*)\\Q")&"\E")
```

Comment: If you look at example 2 sometimes the lines start with non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Jacob Answer edited. Always provide a minimum of five examples, when asking questions on regex. Or ask a new question if you change the rules.

Comment: Good advice. Will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, CHAR(10))), "\d+-\d+-\d+")))
 ,,999^99))), " ", CHAR(10)))
```

[image]

Comment: you're the GOAT